# How to ignore a specific value from numpy column vector, without removing it?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am doing an image segmentation task where I need to ignore a nodata pixel value for a certain function, say for example plotting a histogram of the image. However, I do not want to remove it from the array as this changes the shape of the image. I have tried both of the following methods listed below but it didn't work. The nodata pixel value I'm trying to ignore is 190. My data is of the shape (12350,1)

```
img=np.ma.masked_array(img, mask=(img == 190))
```

The second method I tried was:

```
img=np.ma.masked_values(img, 190).
```

Comment: What is wrong with this masking?

Comment: When I use either of the methods above and plot the histogram of the image, the no data value still have a very high value, meaning that it wasn't masked.

Comment: Most nonMA functions use the `data` part and ignore the mask.  You might try replacing the value with `nan`.  Thats a float. Some plot functions ignore nan data points.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but matplotlib's histogram won't accept `nan` values

Comment: Why not remove the offending value before giving the data to histogram?